# How to perform a function/task on the first day of the month only?

Tags: php

I need to execute a piece of code **ONCE every first day of the month only**. For simplicity, let's say i want to **echo** a string. With the help of built-in PHP functions determining the first/last day of the month, and the current/next month is a no-brainer.

My initial plan of action is to store the current and next month in some variable. And once the first day of the new month hits, only then that **echo** should be executed.

My problem lies in, for one, I cannot find a way to actually store these variables (something like having them as constants) for me to able to compare them.

Comment: I was going to suggest a [cron job](http://clickmojo.com/code/cron-tutorial.html), but I'm not sure what you want. When you `echo` something from a cron job, it just gets e-mailed to you; they're really more for background stuff than visual stuff (if that makes any sense at all).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not just a [cron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) job?  The pattern for a monthly task would be:

```
0 0 1 * *
```

There's no need to persist values or perform date logic (especially if by "variables" you mean something within the application itself, which probably won't/shouldn't be running 24/7 if it's not a service/daemon of some kind, like cron is), scheduling systems are designed specifically for what you need.  (If you're not on Unix/Linux/etc. then other systems have other schedulers.  I'm just assuming Linux since that's most common for PHP.)

Comment: My unit runs on Windows. This cron does sound promising. The thing is I have zero knowledge of this technology. Implementing it for my work may be no easy feat, or it may take quite a bit of time before I could get used to it. Regardless I will surely look into cron.

Comment: @Angelo Tan: Windows also has a built in task scheduler.  You can just create your PHP script and then use the Windows Task Scheduler to set it up to be automatically run at certain intervals.

Answer (score 0):

If a cron isn't the answer, you could store your variables in a text file.

Store a variable in a file:

```
$file = '/path/to/text/file.txt';
$openfile = fopen($file, 'w');
fwrite($openfile, $myvariable);
fclose($openfile);
```

Read a variable from a file:

```
$file = '/path/to/text/file.txt';
$openfile = fopen($file, 'r');
$myvariable = fread($openfile, filesize($file));
fclose($openfile);
```

See the documentation [for](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) [more](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php) [details](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fread.php).  If you're storing an array, you'll want to [serialize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) it prior to writing to a file, and deserialize after reading from a file.